# Why create a table is faster than update a field?

Tags: sql, postgresql

if I create a new table with one week data is 30 seconds faster:

```
-- Executing query:
CREATE TABLE avl_tracker.avl2 as
SELECT *  -- here can change the has_link to false 
FROM avl_tracker.avl
Query returned successfully: 6998969 rows affected, 52587 ms execution time.
```

Than just update one day, even when there is one index for `event_time`:

```
-- Executing query:
UPDATE avl_tracker.avl
SET  has_link = false
WHERE event_time >= '2017-06-16 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone 
  AND event_time <  '2017-06-17 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone
Query returned successfully: 1646479 rows affected, 84109 ms execution time.
```

And recreate the index on the new table doesnt take 30 seconds

Is there something I should check? Im doing something wrong?

Comment: Updating records require that SQL first find the row on whatever page it currently is on and then modify the data. Insert does not require a seek first, it simply writes the data on the next available page. Hence, you are seeing about 2x the speed for inserts.

Comment: @JacobH But then why UPDATE? why not create the table again.

Comment: Because it takes far less time to update a single record than it does to insert 7 million. If you are updating all rows in your table every time, then truncate/insert may be the most efficient way. There are many cases where you would not want to do that though.

Comment: Also, if you create the table again, where does the data come from? Are you going to create the table using a different name (and then breaking every view, function or program that depends on the table being present), deleting the old table to not have redundant data, just because you can save 30 seconds? Seems hardly worth it.

Comment: @waka, In my case seem worthy, because is a process I do several times while preparing the final table. So looks I can just create the new table and rename it. Of course is a single user environment so I'm the only one accessing the table.

Answer (score 1):

It is to be expected that it is faster to insert data on a table without index and then create the index than to update the same amount of data on a table with an index.

Index maintenance is expensive.

Comment: There is also *write amplification* : every page with affected tuples needs to be (re)written ~3 times.

Comment: Can you explain hat you mean? You are not talking about hint bits, right? That would affect both cases. I have heard that term in the meaning "every modification to the table causes a write to every index". My point is that it is cheaper to build an index that to incrementally maintain it with every inserted tuple.

Comment: Well, because of the row-versioning, an update involves:  1) a new row version is appended to the table 2) on commit, the base-page is made to point to this 3) at vacuum-time, the old row version is removed, and the new one takes its place. That is about 3 write operations per update.

Comment: Oh, I see, you are saying that `INSERT` is cheaper than `UPDATE`. That is true.